# mySQL phpMyAdmin with Google Chrome: stuck on loading

Tags: google-chrome, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm using mySQL's phpMyAdmin (installed via WAMP) with Google Chrome and after using it for a while, I can't load things on phpMyAdmin. It is stuck on the "loading" forever, until I delete all my cookies. Why is this?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you running? And can you give steps to reproduce, maybe on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net?

Comment: Same here (I found this Googling). phpMyAdmin 4.0.9.

Comment: Same here also. Using version 4.2.2 of phpMyAdmin. For now, I'm going to use Firefox for this.

Comment: How about you start using Linux? Or at least try XAMPP, I never had those problems with xampp. But seriously, consider Linux, cause you'll never run PHP on windows as you will on Linux.

Comment: If you still want to use PHP/MySQL on Windows, consider IIS. I know it's not the best, but for most mid level projects, it does make for a reasonably good web server, and I have never had any problems till date. I am a WIMP!!

Comment: don't see how that'll help with a browser issue but sure switching to linux would get invalidate the cookie alright.

Comment: For future visitors, the issue might be with xdebug extension. Please deactivate and try again

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be some of my browser extensions. The easiest way to fix this is to basically disable them all (just to be sure) or do it the lazy way: run phpMyAdmin in incognito mode.

Comment: Running in incognito mode changed nothing for me :-(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by following these steps:

1. Rename folder `mysql/data` to `mysql/data_old`
2. Make a copy of `mysql/backup` folder and name it as `mysql/data`
3. Copy all your database folders from `mysql/data_old` into `mysql/data` (except `mysql`, `performance_schema`, and `phpmyadmin` folders)
4. Copy `mysql/data_old/ibdata1` file into `mysql/data` folder
5. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel, If it is started already then restart it.

Enjoy!

Comment: OP is asking for the solution in WAMP

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and turns out, i had a python console running where I had opened up an sqlalchemy session and querying against the same database. Im guessing the rows from the table got locked and when i was trying to do any operation from the phpmyadmin interface, the database was not responding

I killed the python console and phpmyadmin started responding as before.

```
> ps auxww | grep 'python' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

So long story short - check if there any other processes that have locked the tables in the database

Comment: i restarted my computer. and still wont work. so -1 from me

Comment: did you try killing the python process @lone_coder ?

Comment: there's no python process. i just restarted the computer

Answer (score 2):

Typically when this issue occurs, phpMyAdmin has encountered an error and it sends a request to the server to the error_report.php endpoint, then when the response comes back it will send another request to the server to error_report.php, on and on and on forever.  This places increased load on the web server, causing the CPU usage to increase quite a lot.  If you're having this problem on localhost, after a short while you may hear your computer fan kick up a notch or two and get louder.

In one case this seemed to happen when some tables were locked and phpMyAdmin was trying to access them at the same time as another process.  In another case, session or cookie data seemed to be corrupt/incorrect.

Solutions to attempt include:

1. Logout from phpMyAdmin and login again
2. Clear cookies in your browser, then refresh or reopen phpMyAdmin in your browser
3. Restart mysql

Solution 2 worked for me in one scenario and solution 3 was required in a different scenario.  In each case high CPU load was observed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the question is over. Nonetheless, I've got the same problem and clearing phpmyadmin cache has resolved the issue.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: @ibrahimfathy if you are using Chrome just go to the developer tools (F12). Then Application => Clear the storage (on the left) => Clear site data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When i closed/uninstalled chrome's hotspot shield addon, it returned normal. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting MySQL server was the solution for me.

On Ubuntu 18.04 use: `systemctl reload mysql`

Comment: But, alas, not for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem on two different computers.  i went through my php.ini line by line looking for anything that might present a problem.

i came to the "globals" area under the heading "data handling".  i had set my variables_order = "EGPCS" and according to the PHP.ini if you leave the request_order = "" empty it will just use the order set by my variables_order.  well somehow that was breaking phpmyadmin and making it hang up, leaving the loading screen on the page forever.

so i just put the GET & POST value back in the request_order (ex: request_order = "GP") and that fixed it for me.  i checked it a couple times by restarting apache and changing the value of request_order back and forth.  that was the fix for me.

so just make sure the value of request_order is "GP" at least in your php.ini file.  don't leave it empty it will break phpmyadmin.  hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

disabling extension :
EPUB READER
Great choice for reading EPUB files, you can esaily open your EPUB files with this app.

fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In my case, I fixed the problem by deleting files i.e. files that have names starting with "mysql-relay-bin" in mysql/data directory.